# Eclipse -> Maven -> Update Project Configuration and Maven Standard Directory Layout

Tags: eclipse, maven

I am utilizing the standard maven directory layout in my eclipse maven project:

   src/main/java
   src/main/assembly
   src/main/config
   src/main/scripts
   src/main/resources
   src/test/java
   src/test/resources

as per the: http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html

Whenever I then use 'Maven -> Update Project Configuration' in the m2e plugin the 'assembly', 'config' and 'scripts' directories are being removed by m2e from source folders. I would appreciate if anyone could suggest how to configure m2e to respect the standard maven layout. I used the basic java archetype offered by m2e to create the project.

Comment: So you have additional folders to the default layout? If so, take a look at the [maven-build-helper](http://mojo.codehaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/usage.html) plugin.

Comment: Unfortunately the suggested plugin has not resolved the issue on the Eclipse side. It seems that after the update maven removes 'src/main/assembly', 'src/main/config' and 'src/main/scripts' from the source path (and consequently from the package explorer). I would appreciate any further suggestions.

Comment: There is a m2e connector called `builhelper` available in the marketplace. I also read that you need `m2e-apt` for this to work. Try if it works if you install those two.

Comment: It seems that m2e-apt resolved the issue. Andre I really appreciate you help on the matter.

Comment: You're welcome. I summoned this up in an answer. I would appreciate if you mark it as solution.

Comment: I've the same problem since some weeks. The problem is that Eclispe is the mostr crapiest IDE today! It sucks in any way. Especially if you are using Maven. Unless you require Eclipse (as I sadly do for the RCP stuff) you should move on to a more stable/better IDE e.g. NetBEans or Intelli J. Even Vim is better than outdated, buggy, bloated and slow Eclipse. Sorry for that: 10 Years ago Eclipse was a great IDE. Nowadays we should abandon this piece of crap. Please let Eclispe die! Working with it is so frustrating!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the [maven-build-helper](http://mojo.codehaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/usage.html) plugin you can add additional source folders to your build. To make eclipse extract that information from the plugin you need the m2e connectors `buildhelper` and `m2e-apt`. They can be found on the marketplace.